# How to declare <xsl:template match> in XSL if root element in XML is very long

Tags: xml, xslt

Objects xmlns... is my root element in XML. How to declare it in XSLT? `<xsl:template match="objects">`  doesn't work. The root element Objects also has a timestamp at the end which is different in every XML that I want to process.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects xmlns="33a8cae1-a9fa-4655-8c3d-b71241bbc99b" base-schema="179" user-schema="207" timestamp="2017-11-21T16:07:50+01:00">
  <objekttyp>
    <_version>19</_version>
    <_id>364</_id>
    <_objecttype>objekttyp</_objecttype>
    <_system_object_id>458</_system_object_id>
    <_global_object_id>458@33a8cae1-a9fa-4655-8c3d-b71241bbc99b</_global_object_id>
    <_uuid>4dfa0f0c-2172-4fa8-be83-34d79ac58cc1</_uuid>
    <_mask>objekttyp__all_fields</_mask>
    <_last_modified>2017-08-17T16:43:28Z</_last_modified>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length is not your problem.
Your XML has an unspecified namespace, which is fine, but when you reference it you'll need to in your XSL, you need to declare that namespace (you can use any prefix)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects xmlns="33a8cae1-a9fa-4655-8c3d-b71241bbc99b" base-schema="179" user-schema="207" timestamp="2017-11-21T16:07:50+01:00">
  <objekttyp>
    <_version>19</_version>
    <_id>364</_id>
    <_objecttype>objekttyp</_objecttype>
    <_system_object_id>458</_system_object_id>
    <_uuid>4dfa0f0c-2172-4fa8-be83-34d79ac58cc1</_uuid>
    <_mask>objekttyp__all_fields</_mask>
    <_last_modified>2017-08-17T16:43:28Z</_last_modified>
  </objekttyp>
</objects>
```

Note the **xmlns:ns="33a8cae1-a9fa-4655-8c3d-b71241bbc99b"** namespace that points to the same string as your XML.

The ns: namespace is added to all the XPath statements in your XSL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:ns="33a8cae1-a9fa-4655-8c3d-b71241bbc99b"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>

<xsl:variable name='objects' select='//ns:objects'/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select='$objects'>
        <object>
            <xsl:for-each select='ns:objekttyp'>
                <xsl:attribute name='lastmodified'><xsl:value-of select='ns:_last_modified'/></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </object>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Creates

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<object lastmodified="2017-08-17T16:43:28Z" xmlns:ns="33a8cae1-a9fa-4655-8c3d-b71241bbc99b">
</object>
```